# Mille Bornes - What is the purpose of the chips?

Tags: mille-bornes

What are the 4 chips used for?

The instructions make no mention of them. Some have speculated they are used to mark "coup fourré", or extension to 1000 points.

Any thoughts?

[image: Mille Bornes game items]

Comment: Not to state the painfully obvious, but do the rules reference them at all?  (If you don't speak/read French you can scan them)

Comment: @LeppyR64 Native french, so it's not a language thing. One clue is that they are different colors, possibly distributed one per player.

Comment: They still sell it with them too :)
http://www.jeuxdujardin.fr/mille-bornes-prestige.html

Comment: That is the set I have, although it's about 40 years old. Thanks for the Google :)  I'll ask them directly on the comments.. and report back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is still exists in the Dujardin Prestige edition.

Sold Here:
http://www.jeuxdujardin.fr/mille-bornes-prestige.html

Rules Here:
http://www.jeuxdujardin.fr/files/regles/mille-bornes-prestige-regles-du-jeu.pdf

In the section for Coup-Fourre:

> Note: pour se souvenir qu'on a fait un Coup-Fourre, on prend un jeton
>   et on le pose devant soi.

Comment: I've always played placed coup-fourrés sideways ...

Comment: That's what all the other editions of the rules do too :)  I have the Hasbro one.  It certainly reduces the component cost, but this makes it easier to remember when scoring in case they get mixed in.  I've never had this problem though.

Comment: Are you going to update your 8-year-old BGG post?

Comment: You have an account there?  I can give you credit.

Comment: In my version, there are different scores printed on the safeties so that [when one is played on the side](https://veridical.net/Mille-Bornes.html) it’s clear it’s worth more. Much better design than using little tokens.